# Use my external IP address with HTTPS to forward to my localmachine

Tags: ssl, https

I'm doing some development and want to point a remote webhook I have to a server I have on my localmachine. I was able to create a SSL certificate on my machine, and from my own machine I can access `https://localhost:3000` and it accepts HTTPS.

I forwarded port `3000` on my router to my localmachine, and it works if I use my external IP address with http, but not with http.
e.g: `http://my-external-ip-address:3000` works `https://my-external-ip-address:3000` does not work.

What do I need to do to have https on my external IP address work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the caller can work with self-signed certificates (which looks like what's you have). Alternatively, check a SSH tunnel service such as [ngrok.com](http://ngrok.com) (free).